# How to inject HTML and JavaScript into an existing page, which have document.body=null, using C#

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, add-on

I'm working on an add-on for IE which will show an alert pop-up when user visit a specific website. In Fire Fox and Chrome, I did this by injecting pop-up code (in html) in to the body of web page so it will show the alert to user. 
In IE, I find some ways to inject html into web page like:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/149258/Inject-HTML-and-JavaScript-into-an-existing-page-w
and http://czetsuya-tech.blogspot.com/2011/05/c-insert-dynamic-html-html-injection.html

but the problem is if I use IHTMLDocument2 Interface, I can't inject HTML to a web page having document.body = null.
I've been searching so much but still can't find any solution. So my question is there any other way to inject html into body of a web page in IE add-on developemt?

Thank in advance!